# Querying distinct values

Tags: breeze

i am trying to get this to work for hours now. I tried the examples and read documentation but i just cant figure it out.

I want to query distinct values from the DB with a name field.
I think this should work but it does not. The method Distinct is not found

```
[HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<MvlOP> MvlOpsPerson(long mvlId)
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<MvlOP> query = ContextProvider.Context.MvlOps;

        query = query.Include("StatusOP");
        return query.Where(op => op.MvlId == mvlId).Distinct(new PropertyComparer<MvlOP>("Id_P"));
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
ExceptionMessage=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MAHN.Model.MvlOP] Distinct[MvlOP](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MAHN.Model.MvlOP], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[MAHN.Model.MvlOP])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

ExceptionType=System.NotSupportedException

So this is wrong. As far as i understand it breeze does not offer querying distinct values. Querying all and filtering is not an option. Any help on how this can be done much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I post this so someone who might need it can use it. Maybe this can be improved in some way. (Inspired by Breeze DocCode (thanks for the Partial Class Api Method in the Northwind Controller :) )

Querying distinct values can be done this way:
To be able to use the Distinct(IEqualityComparer) method the query has to be in Memory as an IEnumerable. An EqualityComparer cannot be translated into an SQL-Statement.
So the where clause applies and the resulting records are then filtered by the Comparer.

`return query.AsQueryable()`: To be able to use skip/take and inlineCount the query has to be an `IQueryable<T>`. Therefor the method `AsQueryable()`.

```
//The API Method ----------
[HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<MvlOPPersonPartial> MvlOpsPerson(long mvlId)
    {
        var query = (from op in ContextProvider.Context.MvlOps
                      where op.MvlId == mvlId
                      select new MvlOPPersonPartial()
                          {
                              MvlId = op.MvlId,
                              Kundenname = op.Kundenname,
                              Kundennummer = op.Kundennummer,
                              Id_P = op.Id_P
                          })
                          .AsEnumerable()
                          .Distinct(new PropertyComparer<MvlOPPersonPartial>("Id_P"));
        return query.AsQueryable();
    }

public class MvlOp
{
...
    public string Kostenstelle { get; set; }
    public string Betreuer_Id { get; set; }
    public decimal? Id_P { get; set; }
    public string Kundenname { get; set; }
    public string Kundennummer { get; set; }
    public string Person_Typ1 { get; set; }
...
}


//The partial class needed for distinct values ------------
//MvlOP cannot be constructed in an LINQ to Entities query
public class MvlOPPersonPartial
{
    public long MvlId { get; set; }
    public string Kundenname { get; set; }
    public string Kundennummer { get; set; }
    public decimal? Id_P { get; set; }
}


//A generic comparer ---------------
public class PropertyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private PropertyInfo _PropertyInfo;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of PropertyComparer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property on type T 
    /// to perform the comparison on.</param>
    public PropertyComparer(string propertyName)
    {
        //store a reference to the property info object for use during the comparison
        _PropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName,
    BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (_PropertyInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is not a property of type {1}.", propertyName, typeof(T)));
        }
    }

    #region IEqualityComparer<T> Members

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        //get the current value of the comparison property of x and of y
        object xValue = _PropertyInfo.GetValue(x, null);
        object yValue = _PropertyInfo.GetValue(y, null);

        //if the xValue is null then we consider them equal if and only if yValue is null
        if (xValue == null)
            return yValue == null;

        //use the default comparer for whatever type the comparison property is.
        return xValue.Equals(yValue);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        //get the value of the comparison property out of obj
        object propertyValue = _PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);

        if (propertyValue == null)
            return 0;

        else
            return propertyValue.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: That works Sascha. Let's remind the reader that everything after the `AsEnumerable()` happens in server memory. You should know that the data set at the point will be retrieved to the server and subsequent manipulation of that data set (including the DISTINCT and any additional filter criteria from the client) will take place on the server, not the data tier. That's fine ... unless the data set could be in the millions.

Comment: If anybody comes up with an idea to let the DB do this i will be happy to swap my solution out for it. So far i have found none.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the Entity Framework (EF) cannot use your PropertyComparer.  EF only supports Distinct without a comparer.